# Expression relating decreasing charge and outgoing current in book does not match Feynman's definition?

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, charge, textbook-erratum

On page 92 of [this book](https://books.google.ie/books?id=pTcJNiRoscsC&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=%22charge%20decreases%22%20current%20flow%20divergence&source=bl&ots=mRVj_IZUu9&sig=AggGcny_FiicWaNfIOcs9GyBZro&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjh9_WrzYnWAhUObFAKHb_BCoQQ6AEIMjAB#v=onepage&q=%22charge%20decreases%22%20current%20flow%20divergence&f=false) the author says that if the charge decreases at a point then this is due to current flowing out of the region and we have
$$
- \nabla \cdot j = - \frac{d \rho}{dt}.
$$
However Feynman states [here](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_27.html) that if the charge decreases at a point then this is due to current flowing out of the region and we have
$$
\nabla \cdot j = - \frac{d \rho}{dt}.
$$
So we have two completely opposite statements for the same phenomenon. Which one is correct?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v2): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feynman is correct and the biomedical book has a sign error.

The easiest way I've found to remember this is to imagine a spherically symmetric current vector like $\vec J = \alpha \vec r$ for $\alpha > 0$. The divergence of this current is a *positive* constant; more specifically it is $3 \alpha$ since we can write it as $\alpha (\hat x~x + \hat y~y + \hat z~z)$ and the divergence of that parenthesized stuff is self-explanatory.

However it clearly describes flow *out of the origin* and therefore one expects $\dot \rho = -3\alpha$ to compensate: this means that it must be that there's a minus sign $\dot \rho = -\nabla\cdot J.$

There is a similar argument to remember the minus sign in Fick's law as well; if $\rho = \alpha r^2$ then clearly the density is greater as you get further from the origin; so you would expect diffusion to create a current density coming inward; but $\nabla \rho$ points outward, so you must have $\vec J = - D~\nabla \rho$ to get the right direction.